# Putting consolidated events data on Blockchain

Tags: contract-development, cpp-ethereum

Our Dapp emits several events related to user activity on the platform. This activity is very crucial to access some of the premium features of the Dapp i.e your activity score will determine whether you can access some of the features or not.
We want to provide our users to Mint this activity as a soulbound token so that they can use this token on other platforms also.

Solution 1: We can run a chainlink node that actually puts aggregated events data on the blockchain. The address who wants to mint will initiate this function.

Solution2: The address initiates the process by putting aggregated data by herself and the DAO members can vote if the events data is correct or not.

Both the solutions will take time to implement, Is there an easy solution for this ?? Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution I see is to directly have everything be handled by the smart contract. When emitting these events that count towards your activity, then you can also just increase an activity counter. If they have enough of that, then they're able to mint.

The next best thing would be to have a server detecting and aggregating activity and, once a certain threshold is reached, it will generate a signature using a private key for a specific user to mint an NFT.

I don't see much of a point in involving chainlink (unless you're a multi-million dapp and really trying to scale and decentralize). Otherwise, offloading this to a small DAO sounds like an easy way to cheat. And typically, a DAO is not a free work-force. Again, unless you're really trying to scale, I'd keep it either directly in the contract or centralized.